# Stream video from camera to mobile and send control signal back from mobile to Arduino via WiFi

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi, camera

I want to make an Ardunio based project in which I want to stream live video from camera (which is connected to Arduino borad ) to my Android app via WiFi and send back actions/control signals from my android app to Arduino to controller servo motor which are connected to Arduino board. Right now I only have Arduino mega with me. What else components are going to be required?

Comment: Most Arduino platforms (there are many) can not handle video.  There is simply too much data. A quick internet search find this talked about many times.  [Here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=451223.0) for instance.  Where the discussion quickly elevates to a more powerful platform such as a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Nope, a Mega is not up to the task. It may be possible with an ESP directly, but it will be way easier with a Raspberry Pi (for example the Zero W, which is quite small)

Comment: you can use independent WiFi IP camera for the live video

Comment: I had heard of esp32 cam which is suitable for live video streaming to mobile buy can we control servo motor from that.

Answer (score 1):

You need good MPU with enough buffer size and nand size for such an intense process

Search esp modules

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the distingtion between buffer size and NAND size? Also: can you provide a bit more information about how it would look like with an ESP?